# Python: how to add spaces between strings

Tags: python, string

To be more specific, I'm trying to print several results of a function in the form of a sentence like so `print str(function(first)) + str(function(second)) + str(function(third))` and so on, but I've come across the problem that there are no spaces between the individual strings.

So, what I want to know is how I add spaces between each of those strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `join()`

```
print " ".join([str(function(first)), str(function(second)), str(function(third))])
```

Comment: You can also pass `join` a generator expression rather than a list, if that's more convenient: `" ".join(str(function(x)) for x in [first, second, third])`

Comment: Alternatively, `" ".join(map(lambda x: str(function(x)), (first, second, third)))`

Comment: Since i'm new to `join()`, what advantages/disadvantages does it have when compared to just doing `print function(first), function(second)`, etc.

Comment: It is faster. With '+' operator you create new string with each concatenation. `str.join` is optimized, so there is less memory allocation and deallocation. Also it is more 'pythonic'. You want do just that - join results of your functions in one sentence, right?

Answer (score 3):

```
print function(first), function(second), function(third)
```

or use string formatting:

```
print '{0} {1} {2}'.format(function(first), function(second), function(third))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print str(function(first)) + ' ' + str(function(second)) + ' ' + str(function(third))
```